The code snippet window sometimes doesn't close
The code snippet window sometimes doesn't close. Below is an example of this issue on SO with Chrome + Windows 10 when I was writing a question, which prevented me from continuing to write the question (aside from opening a new browser tab). I don't know how to repro.


The screen recording was taken on 2024-05-09 at 15:42Z.

There must have been a JavaScript error at that moment. Maybe a flaky network connection? When it happens again, can you open the developer console (hit F12) and see if that spits out any errors? With a bit of luck it captured the last error.

@rene Good connection (e.g., was able to open a new tab while this tab had this issue) and no JS error (I didn't type anything in the box). Thanks, sounds good, will F12 if I see that again.

I just tried and couldn't repro either. I played a bit with switching between the ask wizard / normal ask page to see if that new Rich Text editor somehow interferes but no luck.

@rene thanks, same, I couldn't trigger the issue again. After seeing the issue, I kept the tab open for a while to check on it from time to time, and  the code snippet window still couldn't get closed (only on that tab, while other tabs worked fine to close the code snippet window and doing whatever else I was doing).

@testing-ma-lady Thanks, the gif consistently doesn't upload to SE, pretty much  surely due to its resolution.

@testing-ma-lady Thanks, got it, the issue was happening on 2024-05-09 at 15:42Z (that's when I took the screen recording). I've just added the info to the question.

Resized using this online service.
